# How to start/open a file/folder that contains space in its name through Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash

I'm using a Windows computer. I gave the correct `cd` and I tried using the `start` keyword to open the files and folder that contain space(s)in their name, but I'm unable to open that.
I have tried the following queries (testing on "My Files")

```
start My\ Files
start "My Files"
start "My\ Files"
```

None of them worked, It only opens a new "Command Prompt" window with the title of the folder in the title bar.

Comment: I think you have to cd into them and run `$ start .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this query and it worked.

```
start "" "My Files"
```

Answer (score 0):

Start command opens a new command window and also runs the specified command.

So to open your the file you need to do `start cd "My files"`

Answer (score 0):

Same query occurred with me when I'm trying to open a folder which name contain space.

Then I try this

```
$cd "folder name"
```